# iOS 7 lays out accessoryView and accessoryType differently?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

Anyone else notice that iOS 7 lays out custom accessoryViews differently than built-in accessoryTypes?

Like this:

[image]

The top one is done using:

```
cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryButton;
```

(where accessoryButton is a customized UIButton) while the second one is done using:

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Same code, same app, same Xcode, but running on iOS 6 instead:

[image]

Is this a bug in the SDK?  Or something I can control via code?

Comment: There has been some changes as to how autolayout works, look at the documentation for tranferring to ios7. (cba to find link sorry)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are sub-classing the `UITableViewCell` you can adjust it in `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect accessoryViewFrame = self.accessoryView.frame;
    accessoryViewFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(accessoryViewFrame);
    self.accessoryView.frame = accessoryViewFrame;
}
```

Comment: And if you are not subclassing the cell?

Comment: No longer working in iOS 8? All values of `accessoryViewFrame.size` and `accessoryViewFrame.origin` are equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, from iOS8 and iOS9 the accessoryView frame is "(CGRect) _accessoryFrame = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))"

Answer (score 0):

Add subview instead of accessoryView

```
UIButton *indicatorBtn = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
indicatorBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-55, 2, 50, 50);
[indicatorBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_indicator.png"] 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
indicatorBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//indicatorBtn.alpha = 0.5;
indicatorBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[indicatorBtnaddTarget:self action:@selector(method:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:indicatorBtn];
```